# Splitting Google Sheets Script?

Tags: google-sheets

```js
function doGet(e){
  Logger.log("--- doGet ---");
 
 var tag = "",
     value = "";
 
  try {
 
    // this helps during debuggin
    if (e == null){e={}; e.parameters = {tag:"test",value:"-1"};}
 
    tag = e.parameters.tag;
    value = e.parameters.value;
    

    
    // save the data to spreadsheet
    save_data(tag, value);
    
 
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Wrote:\n  tag: " + tag + "\n  value: " + value);
 
  } catch(error) { 
    Logger.log(error);    
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("oops...." + error.message 
                                            + "\n" + new Date() 
                                            + "\ntag: " + tag +
                                            + "\nvalue: " + value);
  }  
}
 
// Method to save given data to a sheet
function save_data(tag, value){
  Logger.log("--- save_data ---"); 
 
     
  
  try {
    var dateTime = new Date();
 
    // Paste the URL of the Google Sheets starting from https thru /edit
    // For e.g.: https://docs.google.com/..../edit 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HYJRHfJVgZp16xYt4fipR1bH2BudhuQ4UrDhAf1rBKw/edit");
    var dataLoggerSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Datalogger");
 
 
    // Get last edited row from DataLogger sheet
    var row = dataLoggerSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
    
   
 
    // Start Populating the data
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("A" + row).setValue(row -1); // ID
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("B" + row).setValue(dateTime); // dateTime
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C" + row).setValue(tag); // tag
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("D" + row).setValue(value); // value
    //dataLoggerSheet.getRange("E" + row).setValue(value); // value
    //dataLoggerSheet.getRange("F" + row).setValue(value); // value
 
    // Update summary sheet
    summarySheet.getRange("B1").setValue(dateTime); // Last modified date
    // summarySheet.getRange("B2").setValue(row - 1); // Count 
  }
 
  catch(error) {
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
 
  Logger.log("--- save_data end---"); 
}
```

In the example above, inside the value of "tag" there is data in the format "12345678912 | ABCDEFGHIJ". "Tag" data in column C; I want to print with the first 11 characters in column D. The "tag" data in column C; I want to print it with column E after 12 characters. How can I do that?

To see my overall objective, these two screenshots should show it.

Original Spreadsheet from Form:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqbtc.jpg)

Formatted Version of Spreadsheet:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLTPG.jpg)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manipulate the `tag` string in order to get the values you want.

In order to do this you will have change this:

```
dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C" + row).setValue(tag); // tag
```

To this:

```
dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C" + row).setValue(tag.slice(0,tag.indexOf('|')); //first part of tag
dataLoggerSheet.getRange("D" + row).setValue(tag.slice(tag.indexOf('|') + 2)); // second part of tag
dataLoggerSheet.getRange("E" + row).setValue(value); // value
```

#### Explanation

The above snippet makes use of the `indexOf` and `slice` methods from JavaScript in order to get the index of the `|` character in order to be able to split the `tag` string into two different strings.

#### Reference

- [JavaScript Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice);
- [JavaScript Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I change the code, no data appears in the "C" and "D" columns.

Comment: I am not getting any errors. But there is no data in columns C and D.

Comment: When using the code above, I am able to successfully "split" the `tag` value. Can you do `console.log(tag.slice(0,tag.indexOf('|'))` and `console.log(tag.slice(tag.indexOf('|') + 2))`? What results are you getting?

Comment: thanks for the answer. I solved the problem as follows;
var bilgi= tag.toString();
dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C" + row).setValue(bilgi.slice(0,bilgi.indexOf("|")));
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("D" + row).setValue(bilgi.slice(bilgi.indexOf("|") + 1));